# CocoaLibSpotify Download/Cache Playlist Tracks Issue

Tags: ios, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0, libspotify

I'm having some difficulty with CocoaLibSpotify, I'm trying to cache/download a playlist to my IPad thorough my app but I cant seem to be able to get it to download.

I could do with a step by step if possible

I've had a look at these links to no avail-

[Spotify API for ios: download , save , access tracks from ios spotify api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11347903/spotify-api-for-ios-download-save-access-tracks-from-ios-spotify-api)

[CocoaLibSpotify resets offline available tracks to SP_TRACK_OFFLINE_WAITING during log in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356916/cocoalibspotify-resets-offline-available-tracks-to-sp-track-offline-waiting-duri)

In my code I have selected a playlist and then setMarkedForOfflinePlayback to YES

It suspect I'm doing something completely wrong

EDIT:

I have successfully downloaded a playlist from spotify, the playlist is a subscribed playlist.

All the tracks download successfully and continue to download after the app has gone into background and then to foreground.

I have this code in place on

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier identifier = [application   beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:identifier];
}];

[[SPSession sharedSession] flushCaches:^{
    ALog(@"Flush Cache");

    if (identifier != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:identifier];
}];

}
```

as per the empty cocoalibspotify app

on terminate I have

```
 [[SPSession sharedSession] logout:^(void){
    ALog(@"LOGGED OUT");
}];
```

The problem I have is that if I terminate the app after it moves to background and while a playlist is downloading or has fully downloaded the other tracks don't download when I start the app again and even if they have all downloaded offlinestatus is SP_PLAYLIST_OFFLINE_STATUS_YES. 
I have tried flushing the cache one a playlist has been marked for offline playback.

Can anybody help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Offline playlists using CocoaLibSpotify](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143882/offline-playlists-using-cocoalibspotify)

Comment: Does the update help, can you point out where I'm going wrong?